# Saving regex matches on a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a file of accounts that looks like this

```
<A0001><$241><div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1535.png"width="64" height="64"></div><1231>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1510.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1403.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1388.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1323.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1322.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1172.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1069.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/0966.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/0796.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1430.png"width="64" height="64"></div>


<A0002><$111><div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1535.png"width="64" height="64"></div><3112>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1510.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1403.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1388.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1323.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1322.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1172.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1069.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/0966.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/0796.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="/static/assets/images/thumb/1430.png"width="64" height="64"></div>
...
```

As you can see the images aren't a fixed number, they are different from one to another.
I already have a script that uses regex to find the image's name, but how can I find all the images on the file and save them to a list with every index having all the image names of the specific account. Like this

```
List = [

'src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"'

,

'src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"'


,
'src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"
src="resources/images/thumb/1129.png"'

] # And so on
```

EDITED: I also edited how the file may really look, so the split() method may not work at all, sorry for all the misunderstanding

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if file has space before `A0002` , etc then first `split` file on spaces to create separated parts and later get name from first line and search file in rest of this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to "group" images under specific section. For example:

```py
import re

r1 = re.compile(r"A\d+")
r2 = re.compile(r'src="(.*)"')

out, key = {}, None
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if r1.match(line):
            key = line.strip()
        elif (m := r2.match(line)) :
            out.setdefault(key, []).append(m.group(1))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "A0001": [
        "resources/images/thumb/1634.png",
        "resources/images/thumb/1234.png",
        "resources/images/thumb/1145.png",
        "resources/images/thumb/1243.png",
    ],
    "A0002": [
        "resources/images/thumb/1129.png",
        "resources/images/thumb/1235.png",
    ],
}
```

---

EDIT: To get only images:

```py
import re

r = re.compile(r'src="(.*)"')

out = []
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if (m := r.match(line)) :
            out.append(m.group(1))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    "resources/images/thumb/1634.png",
    "resources/images/thumb/1234.png",
    "resources/images/thumb/1145.png",
    "resources/images/thumb/1243.png",
    "resources/images/thumb/1129.png",
    "resources/images/thumb/1235.png",
]
```

Comment: That exactly what I meant. But I have a whole script that finds the account name and price and write it into a CSV, because of that I want to have variable called images that has a list on it with the images of all the account on each index, not a dict but a list.

Comment: Andrej, sorry if I caused some misunderstanding to you with my weak English, but let me clarify what I meant, the first answer was perfect, but it printed a list inside a dict, how can I ignore the dict qnd just print the list only without the "{A0001:} "  just the images grouped with every account images in an index inside a list like the perfect first answer?

Comment: @TheNerdy97 It's better if you edit your question and put there exact output you want from the sample input.

Comment: @TheNerdy97 don't you know how to work with dictionary? You can use `.values()` to get all values from dictionary - and this will give it as list of sublist. And you can use `for`-loop to display every sublist.

Comment: @TheNerdy97 Looking at your updated question, you can use my first answer and do `print(list(out.values()))`.